# Can I add an interface to a generated Service class via cxf-codegen-plugin

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb

Here's my scenario: I am using the cxf-codegen-plugin to generate sources for a SOAP service client.  The generation and the service proxy are working fine however I would like my generated service class, which is currently extending javax.xml.ws.Service, to also implement a concretely defined interface.

I've been pouring over the JAXB and JAXWS docs but haven't quite found what I'm looking for.  Most examples I have found talk about applying bindings to complex types.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the Unsupported binding interface issue you need to ensure your dependency for jaxb-basics is included in the configuration (as per lexicore's answer).

In addition, you should also include the -Xinheritance flag.

```
     </bindingFiles>
     <extraargs>
         <extraarg>-xjc-Xinheritance</extraarg>
     </extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a class or implement an interface using my [inheritance plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin). See also [Using JAXB2 Basics Plugins with CXF](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Using+JAXB2+Basics+Plugins+with+CXF).

Fragment of `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/CustomerService.wsdl</wsdl>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xml</bindingFile>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-xjc-XhashCode</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xequals</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
            </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version><!-- version --></version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Bindings:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="inheritance">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="customer.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='customer']">
            <inheritance:implements>com.acme.foo.Actor</inheritance:implements>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Not quite sure if it's all actual, I've tried it quite a while ago and seems I don't have a test project at hand.

Comment: Doesn't really work for me.  I just keep running into the following error: [ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http/jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?
  line 7 of type.xsd.  I am able to generate classes without inheritance just fine.  Also, it appears the project page is down: http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Inheritance+plugin

Comment: Same issue here! Also getting "[ERROR] Unsupported binding namespace "http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance". Perhaps you meant "http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"?" What is needed to get this "inheritance"-thingy to work???

Comment: @mmo This works as described above. Ask an extra question if you want more details.

Comment: This example adds inheritance to the objects in the schema. The OP specifically asked to add inheritance to the Service object, which is defined in the WSDL? Unless I'm missing something, this answer doesn't address the question at all?

Comment: You are right. This answer only addresses inheritance in the model, not in the service classes.